# Solving for a seed value in R

Tags: performance, r, statistics

I'm trying to reproduce a `gbm` model which was estimated without a `set.seed` value. To do so I need to determine what seed was used, which I can figure out based on one of the summary metrics from the estimated model (as shown below).

```
require(MatchIt)
require(gbm)
data("lalonde")
i <- 1
while(!(tmp$rel.inf[1] == 82.3429390)){
          gps <- gbm(treat ~ age + educ + nodegree + re74 + re75, 
                     distribution = "bernoulli", 
                     data = lalonde, n.trees = 100, 
                     interaction.depth = 4, 
                     train.fraction = 0.8, shrinkage=0.0005,
                     set.seed(i))
          tmp <- summary(gps, plotit=F)
          cat(i,"\n")
          i <- i + 1
}
```

I think it would be very helpful both for this specific use case and for general future reference to know of any more efficient way of carrying this out. A multicore solution might be a good way to go; I'm researching that myself now. Or perhaps there's a way to improve it by using `apply`?

Comment: You are forgetting about floating point and rounding errors. Your condition for exiting should be that you are within some good confidence of the target. Assuming you read `"82.3429390"` in a publication, then it's likely that the true experimental value was between `82.34293895` and `82.34293905`.

Comment: @flodel I would think so as well, except that I can replicate every number in the article to the 8th (max) decimal place except for the results of this one model.

Comment: This might not be useful, but why are you using `set.seed(i)` as an argument to `gbm`? `set.seed` returns `NULL` so you are essentially passing `NULL` as an unnamed argument to `gbm` and potentially messing up with it. Should you instead be running `set.seed(i)` as its own statement, before calling `gbm`?

Comment: Here is a small reproducible example to what I was trying to explain with the rounding errors: `set.seed(123); x = runif(1); print(x)` gives me `[1] 0.2875775`. But now if I run `set.seed(123); runif(1) == 0.2875775` it returns `FALSE`. What I am saying is that your condition for exiting the loop should be `while(abs(tmp$rel.inf[1] - 82.3429390) > eps)` for some small `eps`, probably 5e-8.

Comment: @flodel `set.seed()` is a valid argument to `gbm`. I got it from the manual page and when I run it I get the same result every time (and it's in the expected range) but when I don't it varies slightly every time. I tried setting the seed at the top of my script but that didn't work for this.

Comment: @flodel "gbm uses the R random number generator so set.seed can ensure that the model can be reconstructed. "

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41887/discussion-between-flodel-and-hack-r).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are looping through seeds to find the one that causes a randomized procedure's output to match the output from a previous run.

If you had set the random seed immediately before running the randomized procedure and have simply forgotten the seed you used, then this in theory would work; all you need to do is loop through the billion or so possible input seeds until one matches. There's no real way to speed up the process (beyond parallelizing, which would be easy because the problem is embarrassingly parallel). `apply` is just a wrapper on a loop, so that would not speed up the process.

Unfortunately, more likely than not you did not set the random seed immediately before running the code. Therefore you would really need to test all the internal states of the pseudorandom number generator (PRNG) that you used to find the one that matches the results. Unfortunately there are intractably many internal states; for instance, the most popular implementation of the [Mersenne Twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister), which you are likely using, has a period of 2^19937 - 1, meaning it has at least that many possible internal states. Clearly it's impractical to test this many states, so it's probably hopeless to try to match an exact PRNG state if you hadn't set the seed immediately prior to running your randomized procedure.

Comment: I didn't run the original model. I'm trying to replicate the results of a journal article. Could you please show the code for parallelization? I'd like to at least try testing 1 through 1 billion, just so that I can show I tried if nothing else. I've heard lots of stories of researchers having figured out other researchers' seed values (I don't know how, maybe they picked memorable values like the year or a birthday). I've managed to test the first 2 million potential seed values since I wrote the question.